# Revisit "How can I visualize the nuclear norm ball"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, nuclear-norm

<sub>Revisiting [How can I visualize the nuclear norm ball?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099320/how-can-i-visualize-the-nuclear-norm-ball)</sub>

---

Two eigenvalues are reproduced as following:

$$ s_{1,2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{x^2+2y^2+z^2\pm|x+z|\sqrt{(x-z)^2+4y^2}}. $$

According to the following (from a paper)
[image]

If a symmetric matrix: $$ A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} x & y\\ y & z\end{array} \right)$$
is rank $1$, then $y=\sqrt{xz}$, which comes from the fact that $vv^T$ is rank $1$ and any rank $1$ matrix can be represented in this form.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} v_1\\ v_2\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} v_1 & v_2\end{array}\right]=\left( \begin{array}{cc} v_1^2 & v_1v_2\\ v_1v_2 & v_2^2\end{array} \right)$$

> My question: how to explain the red circle in figure (b) is the $2\times 2$ symmetric unit-Euclidean-norm rank $1$ matrix?
> This is a circle in $3$-D, how to get the equation of this circle through the rank $1$ matrix provided above?

I believe just replace $y=\pm\sqrt{xz}$ in $s_{1,2}$ and can get the answer.

So I choose the larger one of $s_{1,2}$:

$$ s_{\max}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{x^2+2y^2+z^2 + |x+z|\sqrt{(x-z)^2+4y^2}}= \sqrt{2(x+z)^2}=1 (\text{unit norm})$$

Comment: Not sure how you got that formula, but I get $\frac12 (x + z \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 2xz + z^2 + 4y^2})$ as the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @Rahul you mean $s_{1,2}$? that is from the link I provide.

Comment: Maybe it's equivalent, but it seems more complicated than necessary. Also only *positive semidefinite* rank 1 matrices can be represented as $vv^T$; to represent all rank 1 matrices you need $\pm vv^T$, equivalently $y=\pm\sqrt{xz}$.

Comment: From which paper?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0621.pdf, page 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the linked question shows that the curved side of the "cylinder" satisfies the equation
$$(x-z)^2+4y^2=1$$
and its planar caps satisfy
$$(x+z)^2=1.$$
The red curves are the intersection of the two surfaces, so they satisfy both equations. Therefore, they must also satisfy their sum,
$$x^2+4y^2+z^2=2.$$
Thus the curves lie on the intersection of the ellipsoid $x^2+4y^2+z^2=2$ and the planes $x+z=\pm1$, so they are ellipses (but not necessarily circles).

Comment: The intersections of $(x + z)^2 = 1$ and $(x - z)^2 + 4 y^2 = 1$ are not equal to the intersections of $x^2 + 4 y^2 + z^2 = 2$ and $x + z = \pm 1$ (note that $(x + z)^2 = 1$ and $x + z = \pm 1$ are equivalent but the two ellipsoid are different).

Answer (score -2):

$A$ must be rank-$1$ and symmetric. Thus
$$A=vv^T$$
This implies that
$$y^2=xz$$
In this problem, we also have $\|v\|=1$, so
$$x+z=1$$
All of these result in
$$y=\pm\sqrt{x(1-x)},\quad z=1-x;$$